# Como eu poderia substituir uma linha de vários arquivos txt que viriam de um output do ls -l?

Tags: linux, linha-de-comando, sed

O que eu gostaria de fazer é mais ou menos isso:

ls -l | xargs sed 's/regex do padrão que quero substituir/novos dados/g'

para cada output do ls, uma substituição é feita dentro do arquivo usando o sed. Dá pra fazer? Teria um jeito mais eficiente?

Comment: `sed -i 's/dadosAntigos/novosDatas/g'  *.txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui achar uma alternativa para editar todos os arquivos dentro do diretório:

sudo find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i "s/dadosAntigos/novosDatas/g"